# Would Allah accept your good deeds if your intention is only to recieve rewards?

Tags: jannah, reward

As far as I know, if we worship Allah or do any good deeds our intention should be is to only please Allah or do them good deeds His sake. What if your intention is to get rewards or get salvation hereafter? would Allah still accept our good deeds?

And Allah Knows Best.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

As much as I know/researched, it is acceptable to do your deeds in order to (only) receive thawab (Islamic reward); although it will be so better--or complete-- to do that in order to get Allah's satisfaction, as well. On the other hand, it is also said that: the one who endeavors to go to heaven (and not to go to hell), in truth he/she believes in Allah/Resurrection; and de facto s/he do so to approach Allah --which can be considered as a level/degree of approaching to God.

Source: [www.porseman.com](https://www.porseman.com/article/%D8%B9%D9%85%D9%84-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%AA-%D8%AB%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%A8/39004)

Answer (score 0):

Doing what you described is not as easy as you think, hence not merit-less. Additionally doing such implies, belief in Allah, the hereafter, and acting upon which are all very important.

> [Baqara 62](https://quran.com/2/62)
>
> Indeed, those who believed and those who were Jews or Christians or
> Sabeans [before Prophet Muhammad] - those [among them] who **believed in
> Allah and the Last Day and did righteousness** - will have their reward
> with their Lord, and no fear will there be concerning them, nor will
> they grieve.

People would still do wrong knowing they'll be punished and avoid doing right, knowing they'll be rewarded. It's usually difficult for people to see the light at the end of the tunnel. Especially when the tunnel is 70 years long + time spent in limbo. A lot of Muslims have took bribes regardless of knowing it's haram. Have committed adultery while knowing it's bad for the society and that Allah would punish. Have stole money, etc.

From Imam Ali, [Nahj al-balqa: Hikmat 234](https://www.al-islam.org/self-building-ayatullah-ibrahim-amini/third-means-righteous-deeds)

> *إِنَّ قَوْماً عَبَدُوا اللهَ رَغْبَةً فَتِلْكَ عِبَادَةُ التُّجَّارِ،*
>
> *وَإِنَّ قَوْماً عَبَدُوا اللهَ رَهْبَةً فَتِلْكَ عِبَادَةُ الْعَبِيدِ،*
>
> *وَإِنَّ قَوْماً عَبَدُوا اللهَ شُكْراً فَتِلْكَ عِبَادَةُ الْأَحْرَارِ.*

The worshiper of God-Almighty may be divided into following three groups:

1. First Group: Consists of those who worship God-Almighty for the sake of eternal rewards, which is like -**worshipping of merchants**, (for the sake of profit).
2. Second Group: Consists of those who worship God-Almighty because of the fear of God and retributions, which is like –the worshipping of slaves (for the sake of fear).
3. Third Group: Consists of those who worship God-Almighty because to express their appreciation and thanks for His bounties and favors which is like the -worshipping of freeman.”